# Repeating a task daily at specific time for SDK-Version >= 24

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am looking for a possibility to execute a task daily at a specific time in Android. More specific it is a step counter application that should reset the counted steps everyday at midnight. I tried to use Alarmmanager and BroadcastReceiver to solve the task like this:

```
 private void resetStepsAtMidnight() {
    // Zeit für Reset
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResetStepsReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, RC_RESET, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //Zurücksetzen täglich wiederholen
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if(alarmManager != null) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
        //alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY ,alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

This solution works ok, but it's necessary that the user opens the app at least one time a day, because setExactAndAllowWhileIdle is not repeating. Using the second option with setRepeating will repeat the task daily, but is not exact since the new energymanagement of Android. It's very likely that it will fire somewhen after midnight. And in this case it will keep firing every 40 seconds (?), what causes the counter to reset steps everytime. So my question: Is there a possibility like some event that can be triggered like described above to solve the task?

Comment: "setExactAndAllowWhileIdle is not repeating" but you can reschedule it manually. Meaning when event A fires, schedule event B and then do the task

Comment: Have you looked at 
WorkManager: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager ?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thank you good point.. I think I had a tunnel vision here.

Comment: @estn I think workmanager isn't accurate enough for my case. I need the task to be fired at the exact time. Since workmanager depends on Jobscheduler this can't be guaranteed.

Comment: Just an idea - how about you approach it the other way around - use work manager to schedule this job periodically and on top of that everytime you add add new step / user launches application / some service is started you can double check if the state is correct and reset it if necesarry